# Kotlin - Convert Object into Parcelable

Tags: android, kotlin

Hi i have a normal data class

```
data class Message(
    val code: Int,
    val message: String?
)
```

and the @Parcelize version of it

```
@Parcelize
data class MessagePresentation(
    val code: Int,
    val message: String?
): Parcelable
```

Now how to write a converter so i can map the class 1 to 1?

Comment: Considering the 2 classes are identical, do you even need both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this in multiple ways:

1. via extension functions -

```
private fun Message.toMessagePresentation(): MessagePresentation {
    return MessagePresentation(code, message)`
}
```

2. via instance method -

```
data class Message(
   val code: Int,
   val message: String?
) {
   fun toMessagePresentation(): MessagePresentation {
       return MessagePresentation(code, message)
  }
}
```

3. via constructor -

```
@Parcelize
data class MessagePresentation(
   val code: Int,
   val message: String?
) : Parcelable {
    constructor(message: Message) : this(message.code, message.message)
}
```

Output -

```
val message = Message(0, "hello")
val messageRepresentation1 = message.toMessagePresentation()
val messageRepresentation2 = message.toMessagePresentation()
val messageRepresentation3 = MessagePresentation(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create some special logic for converting. The only thing that you should do is create your `MessagePresentation` object with your `Message` object's fields.

```kotlin
...
val message = Message(code, message)
val messagePresentation = MessagePresentation(message.code, message.message)
...
```

For example you can specify additional constructor in `MessagePresentation` class with `Message` arg.

Also you can create extension function like this

```kotlin
fun Message.toPresentation(): MessagePresentation =
    MessagePresentation(
        code = code
        message = message
    )
```